# Moving a div with an image inside?

Tags: html, css

I've looked and looked, but I just can't find it. Please explain why the image in class: secondimage in the following code isn't moving at all. Shouldn't all divs move the same way, whether they have text or images in them? Thank you for any help.

```
<head>
<style>
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    height: height: 100%;
    }
h1, h2, h3{
    font-family: "Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.topp{
    margin-right: 500px;
    background-image: url('gamerbeta.jpg');
    background-color: fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    float: top;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
}

.second{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px black;
}
.secondword{
    position:absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: 450px;
    font-size: 50px;
}
.secondp{
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 1100px;
    text-align: center;
 .secondimage{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 1200px;
}

   .third{
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px:
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class=topp></div>

<div class=second>
  <div class=secondword><h1>BETA</h1></div>
  <div class=secondp><h2>EXCLUSIVE ACHIEVEMENT<br>FOR JOINING BETA</h2></div>
  <div class=secondimage><img src="test.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

<div class=third>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: where it need to move ?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is, and your CSS has a typo in the `.secondp` block (missing `}`).

Comment: I don't understand why something should "move". All the above code is static, no "move" code found.

Comment: close the image tag ,<img src="test.jpg" alt=""/>

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing bracket after the "secondp" class. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax error. The first thing I recommend doing prior to posting is looking for errors or running your code through a checker/validator like W3C. It can work wonders when we don't catch our errors. Try https://jigsaw.w3.org and you can see all of the issues with your css.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you close the bracket } of `.secondp` that would help. Also read about using `absolute` position, you may be better using `relative`